# Compressing PCM

Tags: windows-phone-7, compression, mp3, wmv

I'm recording sound from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone Is there any way to compress it after words? The best will be to have mp3 or wmv files, but I can't find any solution.  The cloud computing will be to slow i think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no framework support for audio compression. Although you could technically implement the algorithm yourself in managed code, it will probably consume too much processing power and your application won't pass Microsoft certification.